# How to get size and location of a control placed on a dialog in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got the pointer to the control with function

```
CWnd* CWnd::GetDlgItem(int ITEM_ID)
```

so i've got `CWnd*` pointer which points to the control, 
but simply can't find any method within `CWnd` class that will 
retrieve the size and location of a given control.
Any help?

Comment: isn't it wnd->GetWindowRect(&rect) ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
CRect rect;
CWnd *pWnd = pDlg->GetDlgItem(YOUR_CONTROL_ID);
pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
pDlg->ScreenToClient(&rect); //optional step - see below

//position:  rect.left, rect.top
//size: rect.Width(), rect.Height()
```

`GetWindowRect` gives the screen coordinates of the control. `pDlg->ScreenToClient` will then convert them be relative to the dialog's client area, which is usually what you need.

Note: `pDlg` above is the dialog. If you're in a member function of the dialog class, just remove the `pDlg->`.

Comment: In official documentation it says that GetClientRect returns void, so I can't use pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect). If I do, I get runtime error.
If you use GetClientRect(&rect), than I always get rect.left=0 and rect.top=0, no matter where I position my control on a dialog!
It's also written in documentation.

Comment: @kobac: You're right about it returning (0,0) - I fixed it now. Regarding the runtime error, the `pWnd` pointer was probably invalid. The void return value is not a problem since I'm not using the return value anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

In straight MFC/Win32: (Example of WM_INITDIALOG)

```
RECT r;
HWND h = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_YOURCTLID);
GetWindowRect(h, &r); //get window rect of control relative to screen
POINT pt = { r.left, r.top }; //new point object using rect x, y
ScreenToClient(hwndDlg, &pt); //convert screen co-ords to client based points

//example if I wanted to move said control
MoveWindow(h, pt.x, pt.y + 15, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, TRUE); //r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top to keep control at its current size
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding :)