# Which is the best way to find position of a control relative to it's parent window?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, mfc, dialog

There are at-least 2 ways of doing this AFAIK.

[How do I find position of a Win32 control/window relative to its parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034975/how-do-i-find-position-of-a-win32-control-window-relative-to-its-parent-window)

and this:

[How to get size and location of a control placed on a dialog in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653130/how-to-get-size-and-location-of-a-control-placed-on-a-dialog-in-mfc)

```
    htext := GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDI_TEXT);
    GetWindowRect(htext, R);
    // (1)
    // Pt := Point(R.Left, R.Top);
    // ScreenToClient(hDlg, Pt);
    // R := Rect(Pt.X, Pt.Y, Pt.X + R.Right - R.Left, Pt.Y + R.Bottom - R.Top);
    // OR: (2)
    MapWindowPoints(0, {GetParent(htext)} hDlg, R, 2);
    FrameRect(dc, R, brush);
```

Which of the methods is better and why? Is the method with `MapWindowPoints` will work with multiple monitors?

My concern is mainly with [`MapWindowPoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx) and multi-monitors since passing `0` as `hWndFrom` will use the `HWND_DESKTOP`

Comment: `MapWindowPoints` takes into account RTL reading whilst `ScreenToClient` doesn't. P.S. maybe you should rephrase the question, someone voted to close it as opinion based.

Comment: @TLama, it might be "opinion based",  but I need to know why and a proof. You gave a good point about RTL. but I don't see a test case here. will `ScreenToClient` (1) fail where `MapWindowPoints` (2) will not?

Comment: If a window has the [`WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx#WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL) style, its content is mirrored (you may [`try it`](http://pastebin.com/MXU2W2Lr)). In such case, the `MapWindowPoints` will correctly return mirrored point, whilst `ScreenToClient` a point as if there were no mirror. That's why I would prefer `MapWindowPoints`.

Comment: @TLama, You are correct about `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`. `ScreenToClien` failed. what about multiple monitors?.

Comment: Multiple monitors are fine. With both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since @TLama is refusing to take credit and post an answer I'll post one for him to finalize it. (Thanks! :))*

---

The most obvious problem with method `(1)` [`ScreenToClien`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is that it fails if the Dialog window has the [`WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL) style and its content is mirrored.

In such case, Method `(2)` [`MapWindowPoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will correctly return mirrored point.

I could not find any other differences other than `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`.

Both methods works just fine with multiple monitors.